# How to grant permission to oracle express edition to access remotely

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I want to know.. Is it possible to access oracle express edition remotely. And how to grant permission to remote computer for access `oracle XE`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

Just enable the port number(1521) for oracle in firewall.

It will work